# How to programatically control Bootstrap 5 components in Vue 3 without using jQuery

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I have a simple collapse element in my Vue 3 template:

```
<template>
  <button ref="myCollapse" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#myCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="myCollapse">
    Toggle to collapse
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="myCollapse">
    collapse content
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to be able to programatically open and close it. Manually adding/removing the `show` class does not preserve collapse animations.

Ideally the code would work like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "myCollapse",
  methods: {
    toggleCollapse() {
      this.$refs.myCollapse.toggle()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably without using jQuery? Is it correct to assume such way would work for other bootstrap components as well?

Comment: The docs say how it's done with `bootstrap` vanilla js api https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript . There's no need for jQuery. FWIW, there's bootstrap-vue that allows to not reinvent the wheel

Comment: bootstrap-vue does not support Boostrap 5. Could you please provide example implementation for the method you mentioned?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but I made a quick codepen to simulate your issue and your code seems to work just fine?

https://codepen.io/ianteoyy-the-flexboxer/pen/rNdaYBw